# MS-Access VBA select query with multiple criteria

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a dropdown box in an MS Access form which is populated by the following select query:

```vb
strSQL = "SELECT [Process] " _
       & "FROM [dbo_tbl_Area_Process] " _
       & "WHERE Area=" & Chr(34) & Me.Area_NC_Occurred & Chr(34) & ";"

Me.Process.RowSource = strSQL
```

I would like to add `Active = -1` as a second criteria to the query to further limit the selections.

I have tried, so far unsuccessfully to add this second criteria and am at a loss as to how to proceed. Any help from the community would be most appreciated.

I have tried the following where conditions:

```vb
& "WHERE Area=" & Chr(34) & Me.Area_NC_Occurred & Chr(34) & " and Active =-1"
```

This does not return any results.

```vb
& "WHERE Area=" & Chr(34) & Me.Area_NC_Occurred & Chr(34) & " and Active ="-1""
```

This has a compile error:

Expected:end of statement

Comment: What happens when you add `AND Active = -1` to the end of the query string?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried in this regard and describe *how* it's not providing the correct result.

Comment: To enhance Tims answer: Add it before the `;`, not really at the end. By the way: The `;` can be removed at all.

Comment: Have you tried `"WHERE Area='" & Me.Area_NC_Occurred & "' AND [Active]=(-1);"`?

Comment: Are you getting an error or simply not the results you expect? Your table name suggest a Linked SQL server table, are you sure the data in there matches your expectations ?

Comment: Thanks for all you comments so far. I have update my post with what I have tried so far. Minty, you are correct I am working from a linked SQL Server table. The Active field is a True/False field. I have tried the quety with both -1 and "True" as the expectation for this field but makes no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from mintys comment regarding linked SQL server tables I changed the query to the following:

```
strSQL = "SELECT dbo_Tbl_Area_Process.Process " _
       & "FROM dbo_Tbl_Area_Process " _
       & "WHERE Area=" & Chr(34) & Me.Area_NC_Occurred & Chr(34) & " AND Active=True"
```

Adding the table references to the SELECT and FROM lines gives me the outputs I expected.

Thanks all for your comments